# Is it reasonable practice to enforce the immutability of all instances using const public members?

Tags: c++, coding-style, constants, immutability

I have a class - which is basically a struct of a bunch of fields (say, something like a 2-d point; but it's just a synthetic example for the purposes of this question) - of which I only want immutable instances. Obviously, I can make the data members private and only have getter methods:

```
class Point2d {
protected:
   double x;
   double y;

public:
   Point2d(double _x, double _y) : x(_x), y(_y) {}
   double getX() const { return x; }
   double getY() const { return y; }
   double norm() const { return x*x + y*y; }
}
```

But, I was thinking maybe it's better to do this:

```
class Point2d {
public:
   const double x;
   const double y;

public:
   Point2d(double _x, double _y) : x(_x), y(_y) {}
   double norm() const { return x*x + y*y; }
   Point2d operator=(const Point2d& p) = delete;
}
```

**Edit:** A third alternative is to enforce immutability using only `const`ness in the declaration of individual variables, with the class itself being mutable, i.e.

```
class Point2d {
public:
   double x;
   double y;

public:
   Point2d(double _x, double _y) : x(_x), y(_y) {}
   double norm() const { return x*x + y*y; }
}

// ...

Point2d magicalTransformation(const Point2d& p1, const Point2d& p2);
```

What's the more reasonable way to enforce immutability?

Comment: No idea, but whatever you choose, your methods should be `const`.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Um, yeah, of course. Corrected.

Answer (score 2):

There is always a tension while designing a class between flexibility and guarantees. Enforcing the const-ness of data members, which precludes assignment, makes for a very *rigid* class: this has a cost (the loss of flexibility) but what is the gain ?

Certainly, any user that wishes to *freeze* an instance can do so using `const`. So you are not bringing any "new" feature to the user, but you are depriving them of flexibility: is it worth it ?

I would think here that you are being too extreme, since the assignment will not work you may find yourself having difficulties using instances of the class in the most common operations (you can make an array of them, but cannot later sort the array).

Thus, I would advise you simply prevent any modification *apart* from assignment. This is sufficient to effortlessly maintain the class invariants.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this considered reasonable?

Yes. In my opinion, it'a better style, since it improves readability.
I would anyday prefer a `const` (immutable) `public` member over a getter approach. Actually, every data type sends certain message if declared in proper way. For example:

- `const` data ==> The member is not going to be changed in its
  lifetime
- `public` ==> The member is read outside the `class`
- `protected` member ==> The member is read within the inheritance
  heirarchy
- `private` member ==> The member is read within the `class` scope only

So here the intent is clear. You declare a member `const` as soon as you are sure that it's not going to be changed in its lifetime. Access specifier should be selected based on where the potential getter methods are going to be used.

> Also, do I really need the const modifier on the norm method with the
>   `const public` members?

Yes. It's preferable, because you need a `const` correct version for `const` objects or inside the other `const` methods.

**Edit**:
Regarding the modified question. Once you have a single `const` member inside the `class`, the `operator =` is implicitly deleted, so you don't have to `= delete` it. It's just a matter of taste. For me, it becomes redundant.
In fact in g++ compiler, if you try to modify such object using assignment, the compiler will generate an error by itself such as:

```
error: use of deleted function ‘Point2D& Point2D::operator=(const Point2D&)’
```

The other statement is a function declaration:

```
const Point2d findMagicPoint();
```

The return type is not needed to be `const`, because it's anyway an rvalue which is not modifiable. e.g. `findMagicPoint() = <something>;` is ill formed.

Comment: About the `norm()` `const`-modifier - why doesn't the compiler infer it, given that all data members are constant? Is it because of inheritance?

Comment: @einpoklum, it's because the `const_cast<>` feature is available in C++ :). Note that compiler just looks at the declaration of the function in header file to decide whether it's `const` correct or not. The body can be lying anywhere and compiler may not be smart enough to make out that the data will remain immutable inside the body. That will be too much of analysis. So it's better to write a `const` version.

Comment: Will modify the third code sample again to make it not just an rvalue.

Comment: @einpoklum, the `const` member is always a superior alternative, because it generalizes the fact that the object is immutable. It's impractical to go and see which `Point2D` are declared as `const` throughout the code. You can declare `const Point2D&` when passing as argument, but it's not sufficient to convey the message that `Point2D`'s values are immutable in the whole code base.

Answer (score 0):

Both will work.

There is most likely no performance difference between the two, as `getX()` and `getY()` gets optimised out to "nothing". [You probably want to use `return y;` in `GetY` tho', it may help resolve a bug or two].

It's mostly a matter of style.

Of course, you will probably ALSO have a `non-const` version of this class, for when you want to do calculations on the point before using it.

Comment: Depends on who you ask - style is just that - not law.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if a fact can be supplied for this question but, in my opinion, using get and set for such small objects like Point2D is redundant. If you going to use these objects as constants, just make them constant. If you are going to use them as variable, then, just overload the operators such as '+', '+=' etc. and use them. Point2D as a data member should be encapsulated, not Point2D's data members. Again, if you are going to use them in an immutable manner, just use `const Point2D`. You may want to change(use in mutable manner) the data of Point2D later on. Constant data members serve no purpose for this class.

Comment: `Constant data members serve no purpose for this class.` ... well it improves readability and implicitly deletes the assignment operator. So it serves purpose. `using get and set for such small objects like Point2D is redundant.` ... in the question it's clearly mentioned that the code is just an example to express the intent, it doesn't matter the class is small or big.

Comment: @iammilind: He/She may use Point2D in other places of program in a mutable manner so why reduce the usability of a class? I can not speak for unknown situations, I can only speak for what I see and in this example adding get and set is redundant, decreases readability. Also the purpose of class does matter when it comes to deciding whether class should be immutable or not. According to my experience, I have never seen a Point2D(representing a coordinate system) type class with constant fields.

Comment: Answer to the first line in your comment: It's clearly mentioned in the question: `- of which I only want immutable instances.`. Apart from that, whatever the approach is suggested is not very much known to many people and that's reason it's not very common.

Comment: Constraining primitive and general-purpose classes for the sake of making it immutable is bad design . I am not going to discuss further.